# Upgrade formato binário/origem

Tags: netbeans

Estou começando a aprender Java e ao tentar abrir um projeto da pasta de EXEMPLOS do NETBEANS. A seguinte mensagem é exibida:
FAÇA UPGRADE DO FORMATO BINÁRIO/ORIGEM DO PROJETO PARA O MÍNIMO SUPORTADO(1.6).
Onde realizo este upgrade?
Obrigado,
Adriano.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema se encontra na versão do seu [JDK instalado](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
No link acima, tem o download do próprio netbeans com JDK já, tente instalá-lo e verifique se resolve seu problema.